# Add Custom Field Set to Contributions Edit/View

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields

I have a bunch of custom field sets used for contributions.  Most of them show up as collapsed groups when I edit a single contribution, but one of them does not.  Is there a method to show a custom field set on the individual contribution?

Comment: Have you checked the field group Settings at civicrm/admin/custom/group/edit?action=update&reset=1&id=XXX where X is the ID of that set of fields?

Comment: has it perhaps been set to a specific type of contribution and hence is only showing in some circumstances?

Comment: the settings just say "contribution" so I assume it should be all contributions - I can't edit that part

Comment: Also check that at least one field in the group is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

To debug this issue, examine the missing custom field (Administer > Custom Data and Screens > Custom Fields) and what exactly it is extending on a contribution entity. Is it for Contributions in general, or does the custom field that is "missing" only apply to a certain financial type potentially?

[image]

Also, check if there are any customization that may be not be showing them. If you are an admin, you can probably rule this out.

Comment: the settings just say "contributions" and I can't edit that - I assume it should be valid on all contributions.  There is a very good chance our developer has hidden it for some reason.  Trying not to go through them - I might just move the fields inside the missing set to a different set I know shows on all contributions

Comment: Yes, if it is for "Contributions" it should definitely show. It depends on the business case rationale for multiple custom field sets applying to contributions. I'm wondering why there are many if they all extend just "Contributions". It would make sense if they were for different financial types for instance. You may look for any extensions that could effect this or if there are custom tpl files in use that could be modifying.

Comment: I wish I could say why there are so many - I just inherited that way!  I see no reason to have so many, so will go the route of condensing them into a set that does show up on my contributions